# ¿Como puedo obtener la fecha mas actual con sus registros?

Tags: mysql

La tabla que tengo es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y el query que estoy realizando para buscar la fecha mas actual y traerme sus datos es el siguiente

```
 SELECT
        registro, 
        vehiculo,
        kilometraje,
        Max(fecha) as fecha,
        actual,
        baja,
        empresa
    FROM
        revisiones
    INNER JOIN(
        SELECT
            `id`,
            empresas
        FROM
            `autos`
        WHERE
            autos.ubicacion_id < 5 AND 
            autos.empresas IS NOT NULL AND 
            autos.activo = 1 AND 
            autos.refaccion = 0 AND 
            autos.condicion IN(2, 4) AND 
            empresas LIKE "24085"
    ) AS autos
    ON
        autos.id = revisiones.vehiculo
    WHERE
        revisiones.baja = 0 AND revisiones.actual = 1
```

Pero el resultado que me regresa es el siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que en teoría es correcto porque la fecha es la mas reciente o actual, el problema es que los demás datos no pertenecen a ese registro en especifico.
Supongo que lo mas recomendable seria hacer el MAX en registro y luego ese registro pasarlo a la tabla de las revisiones y con eso traerme toda la información, el problema es que hay varios factores que obligan a que no haga eso.

1. Los registros mas grandes no siempre son los mas actuales lo que
   elimina la idea de usar MAX en la columna registro
2. Las tablas dedonde provienen esos datos son tablas muy grande y pesadas que al
   intentar realizar subconsultas se queda procesando la petición y no da nada

Comment: No entendi si tu problema es que muestre cualquier dato (en ese caso la duplicada lo explica) o como hacer el query con max... si me aclaras eso vemos de reabrirla o mejorarla para que se entienda...

Comment: Lo que pasa es que los datos que yo necesito son los que están asociados a la fecha mas nueva, para saber cual es la fecha mas nueva uso MAX, el problema es que cuando uso MAX si me regresa la fecha mas nueva pero no con los datos de esa fecha por eso intente usar GROUP BY para que me conservara los datos de esa fecha pero no me funciono

Comment: Leiste la que te marque como dup? Entendiste el problema?

Comment: Si ya la leí pero como me temía GROUP BY no es la solucion y no me iba a servir entonces vuelvo a lo mismo ¿Como puedo obtener la fecha mas actual con sus registros? sabiendo que al usar MAX si me trae la fecha pero no los registros asociados a la fecha

Comment: Si, group by es tu solucion, junto con max, y luego unir esa tabla resultante a la tabla de donde queres obtener el resto de tus datos. Cuando pueda te armo una solucion. Voy a reabrir tu pregunta

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias realmente me seria muy útil que funcionara con GROUP BY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que podrías usar la columna Vehiculo para este caso almenos se puede ver como el id que manejas tiene un consecutivo más grande que el resto para el ejemplo podría ser

```
SELECT
    registro, 
    Max(Vehiculo) as Vehiculo,
    kilometraje,
    fecha,
    actual,
    baja,
    empresa
FROM
    revisiones
INNER JOIN(
    SELECT
        `id`,
        empresas
    FROM
        `autos`
    WHERE
        autos.ubicacion_id < 5 AND 
        autos.empresas IS NOT NULL AND 
        autos.activo = 1 AND 
        autos.refaccion = 0 AND 
        autos.condicion IN(2, 4) AND 
        empresas LIKE "24085"
) AS autos
ON
    autos.id = revisiones.vehiculo
WHERE
    revisiones.baja = 0 AND revisiones.actual = 1
```

Comment: Gracias Felipe, no había notado eso y funciono a la perfección

Answer (score 1):

Vos podes obtener el maximo de una tabla usando group by de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT
    vehiculo,
    Max(fecha) as maxfecha,
FROM
    revisiones
group by vehiculo
```

Con esa consulta, obtenes todos los registros con el par vehiculo, fecha con la maxima fecha.

Ahora vos podes unir esa tabla a si misma haciendo un join, y usando como condicion de join vehiculo y fecha de la siguiente forma

```
select
    *
from revisiones as rev
inner join (
    SELECT
        vehiculo,
        Max(fecha) as maxfecha,
    FROM
        revisiones
    group by vehiculo) as R
ON rev.vehiculo = R.vehiculo and rev.fecha = R.maxfecha
```

De esa forma, ves toda la informacion del registro con la máxima fecha....

Comment: El resultado que recibo si realizo esta consulta es similar lo que puse en la primer imagen  y no me sirve ademas debo evitar llamar la tabla dos veces porque tiene cantidades muy grandes de registros y hago varios joins con otras tablas de igual proporción